# The same classes in gen and src folders

Tags: java, android, scala, android-studio

I have an android project written in Scala and Java. It contains the multiple projects. One of the projects is a library published locally. However, when I compile all the projects, Android Studio always generates 2 folders for that project published locally: gen and src with the same classes so that I get an error:

```
Error:(4, 14) java: /Users/alex/Library/Caches/AndroidStudio/compile-server/my_app123_746df227/targets/java-production/google-play-services/android/generated_sources/build_config/com/google/android/gms/BuildConfig.java:4: duplicate class: com.google.android.gms.BuildConfig
```

Again, the same classes exist in `gen` and `src` folders in that project. I tried different ways to solve that but it didn't pan out.

Comment: could you provide the structure of your project and the location of the duplicated classes (i.e. the two src folder content) ?

Comment: @mithrop - the structure is the standard, the content, as I said, is the same.

Comment: if you have the same classes in your library and in your "main" project (I mean same class name and same package), it will not work. That's it.

Comment: @mithrop, The content and structure of `src` and `gen` folders in **one of the subprojects* is the same because the `gen` folder is generated by Android Studio in that subproject.

Comment: I don't see where is the problem of having the classes from src folder generated in the gen folder...

Comment: @mithrop, the problem in my question.

Comment: I am currently working on an Android Studio project. I didn't have ANY "gen" folder ! That's why I ask you to show us the structure. Then, there is no problem to have the same classes in src and some "gen" folder ! The problem is to have the same classes in two src folders that will be merge inside a unique project. As I told you : only one class with the same name AND the same package can exists. I really don't understand what you're making here... sorry to not be able to help you